# Positive euphemism for "harped on"

Tags: euphemisms, nonsubjective

How can I replace *harped on* with a more positive expression?

> The production manager harped on the new quality assurance regulations for nearly an hour.

Comment: concentrated on ...

Comment: Elaborated on...

Comment: My understanding of this idiom implies a fundamental negative connotation. To me 'harped on' means something along the lines of: disparaging ad nauseam. I don't think there is a way to describe this as a positive thing. If you are more concerned with making it positive than with preserving the meaning of the statement than you should look for a word that describes the fact that he was focusing on QA regs rather than on the fact that he was focusing on their negative aspects.

Comment: Dunno if I'm a lone voice here, but the cited example doesn't read like a valid usage to me. So far as I'm concerned, he'd have to have *harped on **about*** whatever his subject was. Less negatively he might have ***elaborated** [at length]* on his theme.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- Yes, I've seen that usage too. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/harp+on

Comment: I've never heard _harp on about_ [something], just _harp on_ [something]. Possibly an AE/BE thing?

Answer (score 5):

***[dwell (on)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dwell+on)***:

> to linger over, emphasize, or ponder in thought, speech, or writing (often followed by on  or upon  ): *to dwell on a particular point in an argument.*

Though, it is usually used for negative things but not necessarily. It is a more positive expression than *harp on*. Using the preposition *upon* is more formal and less common.

Answer (score 3):

[expound](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expound): "to explain by setting forth in careful and often elaborate detail <*expound* a law>"

In this case, you'd probably want to use it with the word *on*:

> The production manager expounded on the new quality assurance regulations for nearly an hour.

Answer (score 3):

> ***To wax lyrical***:
>
> The production manager waxed lyrical about the new quality assurance regulations.

Comment: +1 if that's what the question meant - continually going on about something in a positive way.

Answer (score 1):

A neutral version could simply be:

*The production manager **spoke about** the new quality assurance regulations for nearly an hour.*

Putting a positive spin on it:

*The production manager spent nearly an hour **elucidating** the new quality assurance regulations.*

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elucidate

> To make clear; to clarify; to shed light upon.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

- *Focused on*
- *zeroed in on*
- *concentrated on*
- *stressed on*

Answer (score -2):

*The production manager **promulgated** on the new quality assurance regulations for nearly an hour.*

> **[promulgate](http://universalium.academic.ru/179261/promulgate)**
>
> 1. to make known by open declaration; publish; proclaim formally or put into operation (a law, decree of a court, etc.).
> 2. to set forth or teach publicly (a creed, doctrine, etc.).

Example of the use of "promulgated on" from [**Merriam-Webster**]:[2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promulgate)

*Her ideas have been widely **promulgated on** the Internet.*

Comment: Have to agree with the Beast here; in American English that is defintely bad usage. You can *promulgate* regulations, but you can't *promulgate on* them.

Comment: @keshlam, thank you for your constructive reply but I believe my sentence compares with "the Court promulgated Rules of Civil Evidence" supreme.courts.state.tx.us/rules/history.asp : I am not convinced the omission of the 'on' from the original sentence is necessary.  I need to think on it

Comment: One can promulgate a law or creed. One can promulgate a law or creed on the internet. In both cases promulgate is synonymous with "spread" or "disseminate". One cannot promulgate on a law or creed.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast and I are in agreement, I'm afraid. It's just not a valid usage with "on" or "upon" in that position. At least not in the forms of English I'm familiar with.